# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

Hey guys I am new to react js and I am getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`, I tried console.log of the object and it is showing all the results but I am not able to display it in the browser as this error pops up. What can be the reason?

```
const search = 'api/posts/search'
const [appState, setAppState] = useState({
    search: '',
    posts: [],
});

const [error, setError] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
    axiosInstance.get(search + '/' + window.location.search)
        .then((res) => {
            const allPosts = res.data;
            setAppState({ posts: allPosts });
            setError('');
            // console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch((errors) => {
            setAppState({});
            setError('Something went wrong!')
        })
}, [setAppState])




{/* console.log(appState.posts.results) */}
{appState.posts && appState.posts.results.map((post) => {
      return (
               <div key={post.id}>
                  <h5>{post.title}</h5>
               </div>
      )}
})}
```

Thanks

Comment: what does `console.log(appState.posts.results)` logs?

Comment: It shows the correct results from the backend. like this `0: {id: 11, title: "The previous demo of this website", post_date: "2020-10-14T22:43:31.217511+02:00",…}`

Comment: Your initial `appState.posts` is `[]`, which is truth-y (so checking `appState.posts &&` doesn't help at all) but *doesn't* have a `results` prop (so `.map` is on undefined, per the error). It's unclear whether that actually matches what you get from your API.

Comment: `appState.posts.results` , the results is because of the pagination I use with backend as this how it is coming from the backend. like this `{count: 1, next: null, previous: null, results: Array(1)}`

Comment: appState.posts.results.map((post) should correct as appState.posts.map((post)

Comment: The answer which I got below solved the issue. Thanks to all. :)

Comment: Then it seems like your default value for `posts` *doesn't* make sense.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you explain why is that or a better way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Because it's an array, but the real value is an object. So either it should be e.g. `{ results: [] }`, or `null`/`undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems you are trying to render from posts before getting the results yet. you can change your rendering code to

```
{appState.posts && appState.posts.results && appState.posts.results.map((post) => {
      return (
               <div key={post.id}>
                  <h5>{post.title}</h5>
               </div>
      )}
})}
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. works as expected. Thanks a lot!